# What is \\?\ at the beginning of a file path?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

Today I found a file in my directory `C:\ProjectDir\Long file name.jpg`

When I open this file properties and check the path it shows `\\?\C:\ProjectDir\Long file name.jpg`

Why is there a `\\?\` at the beginning of file path?

The file name has a emoji and the file name is many words and is too long. Is the file name causing a problem?

Comment: duplicate: [Where is the use of "\\?\" defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68044243/995714)

Comment: [What causes invalid characters (\\?\) to appear before a file path?](https://superuser.com/q/1522528/241386), [What does the prefix `\??\` mean in a Windows path?](https://superuser.com/q/1633462/241386)